# unable to import tensorflow in windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

```
>>> import tensorflow as tf
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\georg\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow-gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 64, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python._pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\georg\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow-gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 41, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util
  File "C:\Users\georg\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow-gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.eager import context
  File "C:\Users\georg\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow-gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\context.py", line 35, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tfe
  File "C:\Users\georg\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow-gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tfe.py", line 28, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\Users\georg\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow-gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 83, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\georg\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow-gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 64, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python._pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.
```

When trying to import i got the above error, does anyone know what i am missing, looks like im missing a dll.

Comment: have you tried uninstalling then reinstalling

Comment: Please add information about your environment and how you installed tf

Answer (score 0):

I am also having the same issue

I tried installing and reinstalling using both conda and pip and
I also tried using Python 3.7 instead of 3.8

But still it did not work. The problem was with my CPU

If you are using tensorflow for CPU, check whether your cpu supports AVX instruction set.

If that is the issue try using your GPU if you have a CUDA-enabled GPU. If your GPU is not a CUDA enabled one or you don't have a GPU, try [Google Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/)